# Combine two links with both prismatic and revolute

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

Is it possible to have both prismatic and revolute joint on the same pose in one object?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23848/combine-two-links-with-both-prismatic-and-revolute/) by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can combine the joints. It will be technically 3 links connected by 2 elementary joints, not 2 links connected by 1 complex joint.

```
link1 --> joint1:prismatic --> link2(dummy link) --> joint2:revolute --> link3
```

You will have to think about how to set it (joints position, links dimension and inertial) so it made sense for your concrete application.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16763/dkoung/) on 2019-10-01**:
Thanks for your answer!